# does nginx support gRPC compress?

Tags: nginx, grpc

I know nginx support http compress which can use gzip to compress http body.
And gRPC is build on http2.Does nginx support compress?
I have search the question for some days. but only same article tell me how to compress in server.

Comment: I doubt nginx would apply compression. But nginx should pass-through okay. gRPC compression is per-message and so would need custom support from nginx. A few years ago there was work to use standard HTTP compression with gRPC, but that work has been long-stalled. Even with that work though, you'd want the backend to compress instead of nginx because of several impacts caused by long-lived gRPC streams.

Comment: Yes,that's true. I use the server compress solve the problem.thank you